# Graph with walk but no cycle

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to find an example of an undirected graph where there is a walk of odd length from one of the vertices to itself, but there does not exist a cycle of odd length that contains that specific vertex.

A walk is just a sequence of edges, and a cycle is a walk with distinct vertices, it starts and ends at the same point.

I'm having trouble visualizing this and any help just setting it up would be helpful.

Comment: hint: what's the chromatic number of a tree?

Comment: @JohnDvorak not sure what a chromatic number is tbh... wouldn't everything be connected in a tree

Comment: @JohnDvorak:  I don't think a tree can help provide an example of what OP asks.  In order for there to be a walk "of odd length from one of the vertices *to itself*" (my emphasis), we need an odd cycle someplace in that walk, though that cycle of odd length need not contain "that specific vertex."

Comment: @hardmath ah, I misread the question. then my hint is that the smallest example has four vertices.

Comment: So an odd cycle with a single edge attached that ends in a univalent vertex would work, going on @hardmath's hint.

Comment: I think i got it, idk how to send a pic on here but thank you!